# How can we host all azure resources in one network having the same Inbound and outbound IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-cloud-services

I have been working on Microsoft Azure for quite some time. I am using Azure App Service, Azure Cloud Service, Azure Batch, and Azure Functions.

Now the thing is, they have different InBound and OutBound IP addresses. Due to that, I have to give the list of IP Addresses to all my clients to whitelist.

To solve that, I created Virtual Network and NAT Gateway and associated App Services to the Virtual Network. That helped me to get a single OutBound IP address for AppService. In this case, the problem is that not all resources can use the same VNet and NAT Gateway (or I cannot find the way). Also, the InBound IP address stays different.

So My question is:
Is there any way I can create a network in azure where only one IP address represents my InBound and OutBound IP Addresses for all my resources? And I can control the In and Out traffic through a single firewall? Just like we can do in a physical in-house network.

After some research, I also found that "App Service Environments"  is something that can be useful for me. But I am not sure about that.             Can I host App Services, Cloud Applications, and Batch in the same App Service Environment? Will there be single IP for all my services hosted under the same App Service Environments? It will be very helpful if someone can tell if App Service Environment will fit my needs or not.

Answer (score 1):

App Service Environments (ASE) only support Azure Web Apps (App Services) and Azure Functions, you cannot host classic Cloud Services or Azure Batch in them.  You might want to take a look at [Azure NAT Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-overview).

Virtual Network NAT is a fully managed and highly resilient Network Address Translation (NAT) service. Virtual Network NAT simplifies outbound Internet connectivity for virtual networks. When configured on a subnet, all outbound connectivity uses the Virtual Network NAT's static public IP addresses.

NAT gateway can be used with Azure App Services in order to allow applications to direct outbound traffic to the internet from a virtual network. To use this integration between NAT gateway and Azure App Services, regional virtual network integration must be enabled.

Typical NAT designs can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-gateway-resource

Comment: Thank You Ken for the response.
I have created VNet and NAT Gatway to manage my Outbound IP as you mentioned. I still have a few queries if you can help.
1. I have associated some App Services to my VNet and selected default subnet. But in one of the App Service it is not allowing me to select the default subnet even if that is in same resource group as others. I am getting this message : "Not available for integration (subnet must be empty and not already delegated)"
2. When I tried to create a batch pool in the same VNet it gave me error about I do not have enough quota to create node.

Comment: 3. How can I make InBound IP address of all the services same? including batch and cloud service.

Comment: For inbound traffic, you can use a standard load balancer in conjunction with the NAT gateway.  That should work for everything, but I will say I am not 100% on the cloud service part.  I haven't used them in several years, so I am not up to date on all the limitations.